# python: get value from dataframe if it exists, else skip

Tags: python, list, dataframe, keyerror

I am trying to get a value from a dataframe using `q = bins._get_value(gene, 'quantile')` however sometimes my value for gene does not exists in the index of bins and I get a key error. In the case that gene does not exist I would essentially like to do nothing. If gene does exist then I would like to do the following:

```
def get_bins(gene, bins)
    q = bins._get_value(gene, 'quantile')
    df = bins[bins['quantile'] == q]
    df = df.drop(index=gene)
    return(df)

binList = list()
for g in gs:
    binList.append(get_bin(g, b))
```

How can I modify my existing code so that if gene does not exist in the index nothing happens but if it does exist then the resulting dataframe is added to the list? I have to repeat this process many times so I am looking for the most efficient way.

Comment: do note that if you have a Pandas DataFrame, it might provide a method to help you do the filtering you're after which is much faster than repeatedly filtering it and packing the results into a list! (presumably to then become another DataFrame)

Answer (score 0):

You can use wrap the body of `get_bins()` in a [`try`/`except`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html) to catch the KeyError and `return None` when a KeyError occurs. Then in the loop, check whether the result is None and append to the list if it isn't None (which means the gene was found in the dataframe).

By the way, the first line of a function must have a colon `:` after the closing parenthesis of the parameter list, or after the [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) following said parenthesis (in Python 3.5+), otherwise you'll get a syntax error.

```
def get_bins(gene, bins):
    try:
        q = bins._get_value(gene, 'quantile')
        df = bins[bins['quantile'] == q]
        df = df.drop(index=gene)
        return(df)
    except KeyError:
        return None

binList = list()
for g in gs:
    result = get_bins(g, b)
    if result is not None:
        binList.append(result)
```